# Ignoring .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, gitignore

My brother and I are collaborating on an app from two different computers -- one mac and one pc. I can't for the life of me get Postgres to work on his computer, and after a whole bunch of hours, I decided to just have his computer run sqlite3 for development (which is easy as pie), and basically have all the production stuff happen on my mac, while still allowing him to make functional changes from his pc. And merge them to github.

The trouble is, this involves having two different database.yml files, two different db/schema.rb files (I think), and different gemfiles, one with sqlite and the other with pg.

My thought was just to do all that on his computer and add those files to the  gitignore file. But if THAT isn't ignored, then when I pull back to my mac, won't I be merging his incorrect configurations to my machine?

At any rate, that's why I was thinking of adding .gitignore to .gitignore. Will this work? Will it create universe-bending paradoxes? Is there a better way to do this that I don't know about?

Comment: `.gitignore` doesn't do what you appear to think it does. It is only used for ignoring files that are *not* in the repository. It does not affect the handling of files that *are* in the repository.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why aren't you just using the built in `development` and `production` environments in rails rather than having separate `database.yml` files? And you _definitely_ shouldn't need two `db/schema.rb` files. If you do, I think you'r solving the problem the wrong way. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: Yeah. I may not understand the file correctly. New to Rails. I'm not using the built-in environments because I want to be able to run development on both computers, and their databases are different. I want them to have completely separate development configurations. That's the end goal. Anything that lets me do that without them screwing each other up would be great.

Comment: The documentation isn't 100% clear that you can combine multiple database configurations in one file. Example: https://gist.github.com/3887049. When you run `rails server -e production` it will use the database configu under the `production` header and similar for the default `development` environment.

Comment: Is there no way to make sure that the differences between the two computers' development environments aren't pushed to github? That's really all I need. I can't do what's in that gist, because one computer is 100% pg, and the other 100% (or just dev) sqlite.

Comment: I don't think that is what you need. You commit both configurations to git, but you run `rails server -e production` on one machine and `rails server` on the other...

Comment: Did what you guys suggested and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are those two schemas really different? They usually aren't.

If they aren't then just ignore **config/database.yml** and create **contig/database_sqlite_example.yml** and **contig/database_ppostgresql_example.yml**. That way, when someone clones repo, he can use SQLite or PostgreSQL by simply copying example file to **database.yml** (which will be ignored)

Comment: schemas are normally different because of the automatic `:limit` option that is added to the `schema.rb` file. Migrations are db-agnostic, but the resulting schema is not, so it is dumped in the `schema.rb` file.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? The only limits I see in my schemas are the ones, I explicitly set

Comment: I am not 100% sure in rails3, but `text` type columns in a rails2 app I have at hand explicitly set the limit to `:limit => 2147483647`.

Comment: By the way, I agree with the approach you have proposed. It was not a criticism, it's just additional information.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't ignore .gitignore

I've always liked the idea of creating local branches for this. I actually go a little local branch crazy... but that's a different issue all together.

- If you want to have a private little work bubble then keep ***your*** branch local only. You control what gets merged into master (*or whatever your development branch is*) and you can commit everything in your local branch to git for history sake.
- If you want to share what you are working on then just share your branch out. But this way you can keep your environment setups isolated while sharing the local branch so that it is visible for collaboration.

There's plenty of good documentation on Git Branching and Sharing so I'll leave that to you instead of clouding the post with links that surely will get broken.

I'm not sure any of us "really want to" be working directly in the master anyway, especially in collaboration efforts such as yours.